# Transform a log file to csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I am trying to transform a log file that looks like this

```
      Name: AGV
   Version: 1.0.00
  Revision: 0000000000
Build date: 2000-00-00 00:00:00

Continuation of previous file

[1639992888.497] [B62FF420] [DEBUG   Wings.cpp:222] Current sidewing pressure: 3410
[1639992888.497] [B62FF420] [DEBUG   Wings.cpp:222] Current sidewing pressure: 4206
[1639992888.517] [B62FF420] [DEBUG   Wings.cpp:222] Current sidewing pressure: 3433
[1639992888.517] [B62FF420] [DEBUG   Wings.cpp:222] Current sidewing pressure: 4229
[1639992888.527] [B62FF420] [INFO    Position.cpp:438] <AGVPOS> 602, 7787.496,
```

To a csv file.

I have tried to remove the first few lines which I don't need and added name for columns manually, then did this, this

```
df = pd.read_fwf('data.log')
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=None)
```

This has worked for the first log file, but not for the other files as I get some additional columns for each one of them.

The output I want to get is something Like this

```
Timestamp.       Code.      Message  
[1639992888.497] [B62FF420] [DEBUG   Wings.cpp:222] Current sidewing pressure: 3410
[1639992888.497] [B62FF420] [DEBUG   Wings.cpp:222] Current sidewing pressure: 4206
[1639992888.517] [B62FF420] [DEBUG   Wings.cpp:222] Current sidewing pressure: 3433
[1639992888.517] [B62FF420] [DEBUG   Wings.cpp:222] Current sidewing pressure: 4229
[1639992888.527] [B62FF420] [INFO    Position.cpp:438] <AGVPOS> 602, 7787.496,
```

My method is definitely not the most efficient, is there some other way I can do this?

Thank you.

Comment: without knowing your other log files I can´t be sure what's the best approach but i would recommend you instead of using `read_fwf` use `read_csv` with skiprows parameters and delimiter '\t'. if you use fwf you have to be sure what the position of your delimiters are

Comment: read_csv also allows you to set the column names so you don't have to worry about deleting the first lines

Comment: @Carlos All the files look like this, except some of them have some lines in between that look like this

`Robot started
Robot charging`

Which I have to get rid of, But the other lines have almost the same format like I have mentioned.

Comment: @Carlos The format is in general like this

[0000000000.000] [B62FF420] [DEBUG/INFO     abcd:000] some message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment this is the best approach (you will have to do cleaning of the data  afterwards but it would work)

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test_fwf.log', skiprows=7, sep='(?:\]\s+\[)', engine = 'python', names=['timestamp', 'code', 'message'])
```

#### Explanation

read_csv can recieve a .log file because it is still a plain text file, so the parameter delimiter can recieve a regular expression the pattern I selected to separe the files is the '] [' characters you have in each line so the result should always  have 3 columns, and the parameter `names` is the names of the columns you'd like to obtain.

the `skiprows` parameter allows you to skip n rows of your input file.

Notice this regex should work with files with multiple spaces between the sep if you are certain that is a tab character you must update the regex accordingly