# Can you Export pm2 logs to .json, or csv?

Tags: pm2

Afternoon

The Marketing Team have lost alot of data at my current place of work.
I am running PM2 in putty
I am currently using pm2 logs 'applicationname' -1000 lines to get the data I need
This works

But is there a good way to export the data

perhaps a csv or .json
?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find logs in
`$HOME/.pm2/logs/*`

and then it's easy to convert it to anything you want for xample: [.log file read and convert to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49730175/log-file-read-and-convert-to-json/49730255)

Comment: Also for CSV (comma separated values) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70473534/transform-a-log-file-to-csv-using-pandas